# Can Application request routing work on windows 7 as Reverse Proxy?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, windows-7-x64, reverse-proxy, arr

I am configuring ARR in IIS7.5 on windows 7 as Reverse Proxy which would be expected to re-direct incoming URL to internal URL of a website, i.e.:

My website is hosted on IIS7.5 in windows 7 at port 82 (192.168.40.132 is static IP of the host machine)
    **http :// < Local_IP=192.168.40.132 > : < Port=82 > / Website1**

The incoming URL should be as follows:
    **http: // < Local_IP=192.168.40.132 > /Website1**

I have tried to configure ARR and URL Rewrite as Reverse Proxy in windows 7, but still cannot get it work, so I suspect that it cannot be configured on windows 7.

**Can the setting be achieved with ARR + URL_Rewrite of IIS7.5 on windows 7 ?**

Answer (score 0):

ARR is certainly supported on Windows 7 / IIS 7.5. I need more details than "It does not work" in order to troubleshoot further. I would suspect it has something to do with your custom port configuration.

This walkthrough should guide you: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: Thank you! I've uninstalled network driver and reinstalled it. It works well now.